# Edit action for many-to-many association

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I'm making tags for news on web site. Using Entity Framework Code First. PostTag association table (PostId + TagId) is automatically generated.
Here are my models:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
}
```

The problem is in implementing Post Editor Action for my administration panel. Create and Delete actions work fine. Here is what I've tried, it updates all the Post fields properly, but ignores Tags.

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit(Post post, int[] TagId)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    post.Tags = new List<Tag> { };
    if (TagId != null)
        foreach (int f in TagId)
            post.Tags.Add(db.Tags.Where(x => x.Id == f).First());
    db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;  // Doesnt update tags
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
//...
```

**Solution**

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit(Post post, int[] TagId)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Post postAttached = db.Posts.Where(x => x.Id == post.Id).First();
        post.Tags = postAttached.Tags;
        post.Tags.Clear();                
        if (TagId != null)
            foreach (int f in TagId)
                post.Tags.Add(db.Tags.Where(x => x.Id == f).First());
        db.Entry(postAttached).CurrentValues.SetValues(post);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Thankx to gdoron for pointing the direction.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Entity Framework` but in `NHibernate` you have to attach the entity to the session so the changes will be traced. I think this is your problem. That `Post` that you get from the page is detached. Am I right?

Comment: Have you checked your DB and made sure that the relation is created?

Comment: gdoron, i dont think this is the case. and what do u mean by detached?  KMan, ye, i checked db, everything good and post create action that is made in the same way works perfectly.

Comment: This `Post` isn't being tracked-detached. you have to load the post by it's Id\Code and change this tracked entity values.

Answer (score 0):

My sugestion:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit(Post post, int[] tagIds)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {            
        post.Tags = db.Tags.Where(tag => tagIds.Contains(tag.Id));
        db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    // some code here
}
```

I do not tested, could you confirm it for us?